# Why is the first part of the code repeating (the introduction) when it should only run once after the variable Round is changed?

Tags: python, debugging

```
import random, time
def main():
  AIMoney = 0
  AINumGen = '0'
  PlayerMoney = 0
  Round = 1
  PlayerChoice = ""
  Result = ""
  if Round == 1:
      print ("You are in prison for the robbing of a world famous museum. You have the choice of either betraying (by confessing your partner's involvement) your partner, or colluding. (sticking to a story, so you both keep the money as initially intended.) Your goal is to get the most money by the end, keeping your reward from the heist together. You wil play ten rounds against an A.I, attempting to beat them and this tricky game. This means there are four results in total, and you both have two options per instance:")   
      print ("")     
      print ("If both of you collude, you both stay out of prison, and you both gain a reward by splitting the amount of money you make in half. If you both collude the entire time throughout every round, it will always end in a tie for both of you. Result: +100 money for each of you.")
      print ("")
      print("If both of you betray each other, you both receive no penalty, but neither of you get anything out of it. +0 money for both of you. Having 0 or negative points at the end of the game will result in a loss.")
      print("")
      print ("If you collude, but the other person betrays you, you will be punished severely by the person taking all of the valuables. Since you put in money to even commit the heist initally, you lose money in this situation, and are put into prison for your crimes.")
      print("")

  if Round == 10:
    print("The game has ended. Final Result:")
    print("AI's Money:" + AIMoney)
    print("Your Money:" + PlayerMoney)
    exit
  User = input("Type C to collude with your partner, and B to betray your partner.")
  if User == 'C':
    AINumGen == random.randint(1, 10)
    Round = Round + 1
    if AINumGen < '4':
      Result = Result + "betrayed you."
      print ("You chose to collude with your partner and they " + Result)
      PlayerMoney = PlayerMoney - 200
    elif AINumGen > '4':
      Result = Result + "colluded with you."
      print("You chose to collude with your partner and they " + Result)
      print("Your money after this round: " + str(PlayerMoney))
  if User == 'B':
    Result = Result
    Round = Round + 1
    print("You chose to betray your partner and they" + Result)
    print("Your money after this round: " + str(PlayerMoney))
  if User == 'Debug':
    main()
  if Round != 10:
      User = input("Type C to collude with your partner, and B to betray your partner.")
      main()
  else:
    print("Invalid Input")
main()
```

I'd also appreciate any help with the rest, as the variable Round never seems to be changed -- Even if the code is run nine or so times to get the end of the game result, it doesn't do anything. I have a feeling it has something to do with the order of the operations.

Comment: You are intializing each time in main function

Comment: (1) What was your input? We need a [mcve] and can't have one without the input. The expected output is also crucial. (2) Should the introduction be only printed once for the entire program (it wasn't clear from the title)? (3) Why not use a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling the `main()` function again, the variable `Round` is getting reinitialized and that's why the part is being called there..

Not sure about the other variables but you need to keep a check on what you need to initialize each time when the condition is being called.

try keeping the variables out of the main function

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short breakdown of what is happening:

1. You call main() and set Round = 1.
2. You play the game once.
3. If Round != 10 (which it is now), you print the question again, then call main().
4. main() sets Round as 1 again, making the loop indefinite.

---

You have 2 options:

1. Go for a for loop if you always will have 10 rounds. After 10 rounds are over, you can show the result.
2. Go for recursion if you can have indefinite amount of rounds. The change you will do here is pass the round number as an argument to the function. If round is 1, print the instructions and if you want to end the game, pass some specific number (eg 10) to the function.